# Retrofit 2. Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 18 path $.response[0]

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Есть ответ JSON

```
{
    "response": [
        2217,
        {
            "uid": 41084014,
            "first_name": "Ivan",
            "last_name": "Semyonov"
        },
        {
            "uid": 191129481,
            "first_name": "Seryozha",
            "last_name": "Axyonov"
        },
        {
            "uid": 22476278,
            "first_name": "Sergey",
            "last_name": "Tikhomirov"
        }
    ]
}


public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("users.search?&access_token=!@#$%^&*()")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}


public class Users {
    @SerializedName("uid")
    private String uid;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String first_name;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String last_name;

    public String getVer() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public String getApi() {
        return last_name;
    }
}

public class JSONResponse {
    @SerializedName("response")
    private ArrayList<Users> response = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Users> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
    public void setResponse(ArrayList<Users> response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

Ошибка (Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 18 path $.response[0]) возникает в переопределенном методе. Уже долго не могу понять как решить данный вопрос

```
RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            mArrayList =  response.body().getResponse();
            mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: а где модельный класс JSONResponse?

Comment: Внизу под классом Users

Comment: Может, подскажете где можно найти какую-нибудь справочную информацию как можно сделать правильно?

Comment: ну ошибка в самом JSON'e. Retrofit (GSON) зашел в массив и ждал объект, а получил число 2217. Как это решить идей нет, но есть мнение, что на бекенде сидят нехорошие люди

Comment: использую vk api :)

Comment: тогда нужно написать свой парсер, в качестве источника почитайте эту статью https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Оказалось, что я использовал старую версию API 3.0. Используя новую версию (на момент написания ответа 5.69) все становится гораздо проще.

Чтобы использовать версию нужного нам API просто добавляем в наш URL v=5.69

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?&v=5.69&access_token=!@#$%^&*()
```

В итоге у нас получится JSON такого вида:

```
{
    "response": {
        "count": 2457,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 53114804,
                "first_name": "Egor",
                "last_name": "Botvinko"
            },
            {
                "id": 28028650,
                "first_name": "Anastasia",
                "last_name": "Alexandrovna"
            },
            {
                "id": 73514238,
                "first_name": "Polina",
                "last_name": "Pivanova"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

После этого мы идем на сайт http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ и генерируем нужные классы.

Надеюсь кому-то это поможет :)